# Lexicographic ordering of lists-of-lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I was surprised to discover that *Mathematica* does not sort lists-of-lists (LLs) [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths) by default.  For example, applying `Sort` to `{{1, 2}, {3}}`, which is *already* lexicographically ordered, destroys this order, producing `{{3}, {1, 2}}`.

Is there a standard *Mathematica* function, or idiom, for lexicographically ordering a LL?

EDIT: If I were to roll my own, I'd implement a lexicographic comparator function, to be passed as the second argument to `Sort`:

```
cmpLLs[_][{}, b_List] := True;
cmpLLs[_][a_List, {}] := False;
cmpLLs[by_][a_List, b_List] :=
  Module[{va = by[First[a]], vb = by[First[b]]},
    If[va == vb, cmpLLs[Rest[a], Rest[b]], va < vb]
  ];
cmpLLs[a_List, b_List] := cmpLLs[Identity][a, b];

(* test borrowed from Leonid Shifrin's answer *)
test = {{3}, {7}, {4, 6, 2}, {7, 7, 6}, {10, 3, 9}, {6, 7, 9}, {1, 7, 7}};

Sort[test, cmpLLs]
(* {{1, 7, 7}, {3}, {4, 6, 2}, {6, 7, 9}, {7}, {7, 7, 6}, {10, 3, 9}} *)

Sort[test, cmpLLs[Plus]]  (* just for giggles *)
(* {{1, 7, 7}, {3}, {4, 6, 2}, {6, 7, 9}, {7}, {7, 7, 6}, {10, 3, 9}} *)

Sort[test, cmpLLs[Minus]]
(* {{10, 3, 9}, {7}, {7, 7, 6}, {6, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 2}, {3}, {1, 7, 7}} *)
```

Not a stack-friendly implementation, I admit...

Comment: You could resort to `ToString` before ordering: `ToExpression /@ Sort[ToString /@ {{3}, {1, 2}}]`  (or roll your own ordering function).

Comment: Another kludge that might work (only on digits). `x = {{1, 2}, {6, 2}, {5, 7}, {4, 5, 5}, {9}}; SortBy[x, FromDigits@PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ x]] &]` But it might give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: This is due to `Sort` on lists sorting by the size of the sub-list first, and only applying lexicographic sort for equal-size lists. This is in fact documented.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: thanks for your comment (and answer); regarding the documentation, I can't find what you refer to in the documentation page for `Sort`; could you point me to it?  (I'm hoping that the documentation makes a good case for the chosen default behavior.  No amount of bare, matter-of-fact description can make up for a perverse design.)

Comment: Glad I could help. Re: docs -  have a look at the notes in documentation of  `Sort`, under details, fourth bullet point: " usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth-first manner. ".

Comment: @kjo That's an awesome implementation! Why not stack-friendly? Isn't it optimized into tail recursion?

Comment: @BlacKow: Thanks!  Regarding tail recursion, I confess that I didn't give much thought to that possibility; I certainly did not take it into account when I wrote the code.  In fact, I just don't understand *Mathematica*'s evaluation model well enough to write down a function that is amenable to tail-recursion optimization (that is, not without a lot of trial-and-error).  But, be that as it may, I just confirmed that no tail-recursion optimization is happening; I did this by putting a `Print[Length[Stack[]]]` statement inside the function, ...

Comment: ...and using it to sort a list of two lists having a common prefix; the size of the stack grows linearly with the length of the shared prefix.

Comment: @BlacKow: based on a quick Google search, I gather that recursion optimization in *Mathematica* is not at all like it is with more mainstream languages.  E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4481301/559827

Comment: @kjo Indeed so. There were some additional discussions on that matter, here on SE.

Comment: @BlacKow The problem with kjo's implementation is that Mathematica Lists are arrays, not linked lists. So, apart from the issues related to tail calls, there is also the issue related to list copying on every recursive step. The proper way to do this sort of things in Mathematica would be to use [linked lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474).

Comment: The reason to sort on length first is that it is often a quick discriminator, hence `Ordering` is less likely to be slow e.g. from deep recursion in a depth first search.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to Sort on lists sorting by the size of the sub-list first, and only applying lexicographic sort for equal-size lists. This is in fact documented.

Based on this observation, here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[lexicographicListSort]
lexicographicListSort[lst_List] :=
  Module[{lengths = Length /@ lst, ord},
    ord = Ordering @ PadRight[lst, {Length[lst], Max[lengths]}];
    MapThread[Take, {lst[[ord]], lengths[[ord]]}]
  ]
```

For example:

```
test = {{3}, {7}, {4, 6, 2}, {7, 7, 6}, {10, 3, 9}, {6, 7, 9}, {1, 7, 7}}

lexicographicListSort[test]

(* {{1, 7, 7}, {3}, {4, 6, 2}, {6, 7, 9}, {7}, {7, 7, 6}, {10, 3, 9}} *)
```

**EDIT**

As BlacKow rightly noted, the above code can be very memory-inefficient, in cases when some of the sublists are really large. The simplest naive solution to trade speed for memory is to make such padding local to the comparison event:

```
sortlNaive[l_List] :=
  Sort[
    l, 
    With[{max = Max[Length[#1], Length[#2]]}, 
      OrderedQ[PadRight[#, max] & /@ {##}]
    ] &
  ]
```

However, this method is pretty inefficient. The reason is that we are leaving the "optimal code" Mathematica's paradigm to work with lots of data at once (it is possible to explain this particular case in more detail).

Saving explanations and benchmarks for some near future (when I get more time), here is a version which generally performs better or much better than `sortlNaive`, while being much more memory-efficient than `lexicographicListSort` (V10+, since I use operator forms, but can be easily rewritten to be used in earlier versions):

```
ClearAll[sortl];
sortl[{}, _ : None] := {};
sortl[{x_}, _ : None] := {x};
sortl[l_List] := sortl[l, 1];
sortl[l_List, lev_] :=
  With[{min = Min[Length /@ l]},
    Composition[
      Flatten[#, 1] &,
      Map[
        If[Length[#] == 1,
          #,
          With[{smallest = LengthWhile[#, Length[#] == lev &]},
            Take[#, smallest]~Join~sortl[Drop[#, smallest], lev + 1]
          ]
        ] &
      ],
      SplitBy[#, Take[#, {lev, min}] &] &,
      SortBy[Take[#, {lev, min}] &]
    ]@l
  ]
```

A question of automation of the choice between `lexicographicListSort` and `sortl` is an interesting one, but requires more time than I currently have, to do it justice.

Comment: What if the average length of your sub-list is 5, but the largest sub-list has million elements? Your padding will be wasting lots of memory, right?

Comment: @BlacKow Yes, you are right, that's a good point! I added some code to address that issue.