# SortBy first element then second element, and so on?

Tags: sorting, order

`SortBy` can sort list by first element easily like so:

```
SortBy[{{1, 6}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}}, First]
```

and the result is:

> {{1, 6}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}}

How do you apply a sort of dictionary order, so that it compare the first element, then second element, and so on (if available). So the above result could become:

> {{1, **2**, 8}, {1, **6**}, {2}}

Because of **2** and **6**.

Comment: Maybe you can use this function (sorts lists lexicographically) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85606/lexicographic-ordering-of-lists-of-lists

Comment: Are all of your lists of single digit elements?

Comment: If so, you can use `lst[[Ordering@(ToString /@ lst)]]`

Comment: Related: [(26974)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26974/121)

Comment: Should be applicable to all numbers. Not necessarily single digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [Pillsy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/531/pillsy) I thought to pad the list.  In the case given a simpler form works:

```
lsts = {{1, 6}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}};

lsts[[Ordering @ PadRight @ lsts]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 8}, {1, 6}, {2}}
> ```

Related examples:

- [Unexpected result {".a", "co", ".m"} from Sort[{".m", ".a", "co"}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26974/121#27196)
- [Sort strings by natural ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10619/121)

Comment: interesting, why lsts is followed by "[[" instead of single "["? Usually function is called by single "[". Is this a different syntax?

Comment: found it in this document https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetElementsOfLists.html. That it's a short form of `Part` function.

Answer (score 5):

If your list contains only positive elements, then this may work.

```
SeedRandom@1
n = 100;
list = TakeList[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n], RandomInteger[{1, 7}, 10]]
```

> {{2, 5, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 9, 7}, {1, 5, 2, 9, 6}, {2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
>     7}, {1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4}, {1}, {2, 4, 6, 4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 10, 
>     6}, {2}}

```
max = Length /@ list // Max;
Sort[PadRight[#, max] & /@ list] // DeleteCases[#, 0, Infinity] &
```

> {{1}, {1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 2, 9, 6}, {2}, {2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
>     7}, {2, 4, 6, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 10, 6}, {8, 1, 1, 9, 7}}

**Edit:**

```
SeedRandom@1
n = 100;
list = TakeList[RandomInteger[10, n], RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10]]
```

> {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 5}, {1}, {1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 
>     6, 0}, {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3, 0}, {3, 2, 3, 9, 5, 
>     1}, {5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0}, {4}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9}}

```
 smallNumber = -100;
 max = Length /@ list // Max;
 Sort[PadRight[#, max, smallNumber] & /@ list] // DeleteCases[#, smallNumber, Infinity] &
```

> {{0, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 5}, {1}, {1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 6, 0}, {1, 4, 0, 
>     7, 0}, {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1}, {3, 2, 3, 9, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 3, 
>     0}, {4}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9}, {5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0}}

Answer (score 4):

If you pad out the lists on the left with $ -\infty$, you ensure that a short list which is a prefix of a long list will come before it, giving you a lexicographic sort. Then you can use [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) and `Part` to pull out the old elements.

```
data = {{1, 6}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}}
With[{n = Max[Length /@ data]},
 Part[data, Ordering[PadRight[#, n, -Infinity] & /@ data]]]

(* {{1, 2, 8}, {1, 6}, {2}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NumericalSort[{{1, 6}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}}]
```

Comment: It first considers the length of sub list. Try `NumericalSort[{{1, 6, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 8}, {2}}]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci ah shoot. `PadRight` it is :-)