# Concise way to do lexicographic ordering

Tags: sorting, order

I want to order a bunch of number sequences lexicographically. Did this with

```
lexo[x_, y_] := x == {} || 
    y != {} && (First[x] < First[y] || First[x] == First[y] && lexo[Rest[x], Rest[y]])
Sort[mysequences, lexo]
```

and it works, but it is presumably not very efficient, because of recursive self-calls.

There is also a version in [one of the answers here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85622/35000) which might be better. But maybe Mathematica has something built in for that?

I suspect this since there turns out to be something called `Lexicographic` for which I could not find any documentation. Also, `Combinatorica` has things like `LexicographicSubsets` and `LexicographicPermutations` except that I want something more general, working for any sequences of numbers.

Comment: how about `SortBy[First]@mysequences`?

Comment: (1) `Lexicographic` is an option value for the `MonomialOrder` option in `GroebnerBasis`. Nowadays it would be a string but at the time this was designed we really didn't do option settings that way. (2) Coincidently, implementing a `LexicographicOrder` for usage in `Sort` and related is on my immediate to-do list.

Comment: @kglr Tried it on `Subsets[Range[3]]`, throws an error message because of the empty set, and sorts like this `{{1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,2,3},{2},{2,3},{3},{}}` which is not quite lexicographic: `{1,2,3}` must go before `{1,3}`

Comment: maybe `SortBy[x \[Function] PadRight[x, Max[Length /@ #]]]@# &@
 Subsets[Range@3]`?

Comment: ... or `(x \[Function] SortBy[x, PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ x]] &])@
 Subsets[Range@3]`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you, these both seem to work correctly. Could you make an answer please?

Comment: მამუკაჯიბლაძე, posted the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[lexSort1, lexSort2]

lexSort1 = SortBy[x \[Function] PadRight[x, Max[Length /@ #]]]@# &;

lexSort2 = Function[x, SortBy[x, PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ x]] &]];
```

***Examples:***

```
lexSort1 @ Subsets[Range@3]
```

> ```
>  {{}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 3}, {3}}
> ```

```
lexSort2 @ Subsets[Range@3]
```

> ```
>  {{}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 3}, {3}}
> ```